# How to query and filtering with multiple elements in typeorm - nest js

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, typeorm, nest, relation

What is the best way to query and filtering relation entity / many to many field in typeorm. For example in my case i have books with 2 categories:
action & adventure.
Then i want filtering by that categories.
so the url e.g:

> ..../books?categories='action,adventure'.

My problem i can only filter with only 1 or i must use orWhere in my querybuilder but if i add the categories to

> 'action,adventure,scifi'

is still got the result not filtering of all of them categories

#### book.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Book {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  thumbnail: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => BooksCategory, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  category: BooksCategory[];

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    type: 'timestamp',
  })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    type: 'timestamp',
  })
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

Here my service function

#### books.service.ts

```js
  async findAll(query: GetBooksQueryDto): Promise<Book[]> {
    const booksQuery = await this.booksRepository.createQueryBuilder('book');
    const joins = await booksQuery.leftJoinAndSelect(
      'book.category',
      'category',
    );
    const titleFilter = await joins.andWhere('book.title LIKE :title', {
      title: `%${query.title}%`,
    });

    const categoryFilter = titleFilter
      .andWhere('category.name LIKE :category', {
        category: `action`,
      })
      .andWhere('category.name LIKE :category', {
        category: `adventure`,
      });

    return await categoryFilter.getMany();
  }
```

got return like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Love is war",
        "description": "One piece is real",
        "thumbnail": "file://",
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T16:36:11.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T16:36:11.000Z",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "adventure"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My expection is like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Love is war",
        "description": "One piece is real",
        "thumbnail": "file://",
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T16:36:11.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T16:36:11.000Z",
        "category": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "action"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "adventure"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

the problem the second argument or the next argument of `andWhere()` in `categoryFilter` is overwriting the previous value of categories array.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why are you using filtering in this way.

You should be using better naming convention for variables. You dont need all those variables because if dont have any conditions.

Based on your code above i would write something like this.

```
return this.booksRepository.createQueryBuilder('book').leftJoinAndSelect(
  'book.category',
  'category',
).where('book.title LIKE :title', {
  title: `%${query.title}%`,
}).andWhere('category.name IN (:...categories)', {
    categories: query.categories,
  }).getMany();
```

You could even can use Typerorm find method for this query.

Comment: thnks dude for the advice, i'm doing it like that for my dynamic querying . it  can be empty in title or categories.  its work but i got new problem. the query is just filtering one of categories in array

Comment: e.g my categories ```categories = ['action', 'adventure']``` then its got the books with category with ```action``` only